# Editing related objects in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, editing, relates

Using `ArcCatalog`, I created a relationship with the following parameters:

- Origin Table: Owner // a table
- Destination Table: Parcel // a feature class
- Relationship Type: Composite
- Message Direction: Forward
- Cardinality: One_To_Many
- Origin Primary Key: ObjectId
- Origin Foreign Key: OwnerId (Parcel has `OwnerId` field of type `Long`)

Now In `ArcMap`, when trying to edit the `Parcel` layer, I supposed -for the `OwnerId` field- to find a drop-down list of values from `Owner` table. but I found a normal text box that I can edit with any number, not just those numbers of 'Owner.ObjectId's.

1. How to populate `Owner.ObjectId` values as drop-down list to choose from it while editing `Parcel.OwnerId` field?
2. How to prevent entries that not exist in `Owner.ObjectId` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arcmap is not supposed to work with relationship classes like that. Suppose an Owner table with 1000 of records. Showing this number in a combobox isn't feasible.

To relate parcels to an owner, first select the parcels in the map. then select the owner with select by attribute. right click each parcel and then click "Add selected" button.

To answer your both questions see the following snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Farid, but what about my second question, arcmap allows any number in Parcel.OwnerID even if it's not exist in Owner.ObjectID.

Comment: ArcMap treats relationship fields (Parcel.OwnerID) like any other field. No constraint applies to such fields. you should  write your own code (e.g. Arcobjects) to restrict user input for such fields.

Comment: Lio, if you think this the correct answer please mark is as the answer. http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour